# Where is Realms icon for 0.8.1?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I logged in for Realms Alpha but the Realms icon is not appearing. Why?

Comment: Do you have access to the Realms Alpha? This is also tricky to answer as Alpha software is typically not widely available and out of the scope of the site.

Comment: @MichaelFrank If you can buy access to it, it is not out of scope for the site.

Comment: @Arperum fair enough. Where can you buy access? I'd like to check it out. :D

Answer (score 0):

You must have access to Realms Alpha to have the button enabled. If you don't have it, the button will simply disappear. To get it, ask someone with a Realm to invite you to theirs and then you can join their Realm via the button which will only appear if you have access to Realms Alpha.

Source: I tried logging in with my other account without Realms and the button wasn't there.